# Play with jquery autocomplete proper usage

Tags: json, scala, playframework, autocomplete

Could someone help me to use them together? Tried a code from same topics but it's unclear to me or just outdated.
First, code for autocomplete:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: //What should be here?
    });
  });
</script>
```

Then, controller code:

```
def auto(term:String) = Action {
  Ok (Json.toJson(equipmentDAO.get(term))) }
}
```

Method **equipmentDAO.get(term))** searches for objects with *name == term* and returns Seq of them.

And routes:

```
GET     /auto/:term                         controllers.BasicController.auto(term : String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable autocompletion you have to provide a [JSONP object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

In play2 I use this patter with some success

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        select : function(event, ui) {
            //... do something if selected
            return false;
        },
        source : function(request, response) {  
            $.ajax({
                url : "/myautocompletionEndpoint",
                dataType : "jsonp",
                data : {
                    q: request.term,
                },
                success : function(data) {

                    response(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Under the route `/myautocompletionEndpoint` I provide a controller that returns the JSONP object.

Signature of the controller method is:

`public CompletionStage<Result> subjectAutocomplete(String q)` .

And it creates a list of results like this:

```
[
  {"label":"Some label","value":"Some Value"},
  ....
]
```

By default the jQuery autocomplete widget will send an additional callback parameter to the controller, for example `&callback=jQuery110208100147994940178_1491819270607`. You have to take it's content and wrap your result list into it. You can access query parameters from within the controller via

```
request().queryString().get("callback");
```

So at the end it will look like:

```
String result="/**/jQuery110208100147994940178_1491819270607([{"label":"Some label","value":"Some Value"}])";
```